# Dynamically Created Combobox's SelectedIndexChanged Event

Tags: c#, combobox

i'm designing a windows form application. In this app, user selects a number from a combobox, then depending on the number, some dynamic controls will be created(labels and comboboxes).

My problem is, i need to write some code on these dynamically created comboboxs' "selectedindexchanged" event. But i don't know how to create an event to dynamic combobox.

Here is my function:

**FORM1.CS**

```
public void getchildCntrl(Panel pnl,ComboBox cmbb)
        {
            for (int ix = pnl.Controls.Count - 1; ix >= 0; ix--)
                if (pnl.Controls[ix].Name.Substring(0, 5) == "Child") pnl.Controls[ix].Dispose();

            if (cmbb.SelectedIndex != 0)
            {
                Label[] childLabels = new Label[cmbb.SelectedIndex];
                ComboBox[] txtTeamNames = new ComboBox[cmbb.SelectedIndex];
                for (int i = 0; i < txtTeamNames.Length; i++)
                {
                    //label create
                    var lbl = new Label();
                    childLabels[i] = lbl;
                    lbl.Name = "ChildLb" + i.ToString();
                    lbl.Text = (i + 1).ToString() + ". Çocuk-Yaş :";
                    lbl.Width = 80;
                    lbl.Location = new Point(cmbb.Location.X - 85, cmbb.Location.Y + 7 + ((i + 1) * 28));
                    lbl.Visible = true;
                    pnl.Controls.Add(lbl);

                    //combobox create
                    var cmb = new ComboBox();
                    txtTeamNames[i] = cmb;
                    cmb.Name = "Child" + i.ToString();
                    cmb.Location = new Point(cmbb.Location.X, cmbb.Location.Y + 5 + ((i + 1) * 28));
                    cmb.Width = 40;
                    cmb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
                    cmb.DataSource = ages.ToArray();
                    cmb.Visible = true;
                    pnl.Controls.Add(cmb);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just register to the event like below...

```
cmb.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler((object o, EventArgs e) => 
{
    //Do something here
});
```

Or

```
cmb.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(cmb_SelectedValueChanged);

private void cmb_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do something here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Register event handler this way:

```
cmb.SelectedIndexChanged+=new EventHandler(cmb_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Unregister this way:

```
cmb.SelectedIndexChanged-=new EventHandler(cmb_SelectedIndexChanged);

private void cmb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //write your event code here
}
```

[How to: Create Event Handlers at Run Time for Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfty2w4e.aspx)

```
public void getchildCntrl(Panel pnl,ComboBox cmbb)
    {

//// your code.....
                //combobox create
                var cmb = new ComboBox();
                cmb.SelectedIndexChanged+=new EventHandler(cmb_SelectedIndexChanged);
// remaining code
                cmb.Visible = true;
                pnl.Controls.Add(cmb);
            }
        }
    }
```

For specifying parameters - go through:

[ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx)

Comment: Error: The name 'cmb_SelectedIndexChanged' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @AloneInTheDark `cmb_SelectedIndexChanged` is a seperate method to handle the event. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can hook up an event handler to the ComboBox like this:

```
cmd.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(GuiController_SelectionChanged);

void GuiController_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```